# Google Data Studio failed to parse a CASE statement

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to sum up a variable `CMTAMT_OVRD` based on the `Fake Date` variable to create a new variable. This is the formula I am using below.

```
CASE
  WHEN Fake Date = 20181231 THEN SUM(CMTAMT_OVRD)
END
```

`Fake Date` is a date field in `YYYYMMDD`

`CMTAMT_OVRD` is a metric

I have already tried:

1. Changing the data format in sheets to match;
2. Splitting it up into different lines;
3. Adding an else at the end.

None of the above was working.

*Failed to parse CASE statement*. Is what it gives me every time or *Invalid Formula*.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the aggregation outside of the case statement

```
sum(Case when Fake Date = 20181231 then CMTAMT_OVRD End)
```